# htaccess Rewrite .php to /

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having a little problem with some rewriting rules in .htaccess

I'd like to rewrite all the .php files for my domain to end /

But im having a little problem.

For example

The page: www.example.com/test/

Will display with any text after the / e.g.:

```
www.example.com/test/123
www.examle.com/test/abc
```

I hope this makes sense, is there a way to correct this problem as I'm sure it probably isn't a good thing.

Thanks

And here is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I'm a bit of a novice so not really sure where I'm going wrong..

Comment: `/test/123` will be rewritten to `/test.php` or `/test/123.php`?

Comment: Question is unclear..